# Class Memcache not found when executing in PHPUnit

Tags: memcached, phpunit

I have installed the `memcached` and loaded the `memcached` extension, but when I was runnning a test with PHPUnit, it told class `memcached` not found. Can anyone tell me why, and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried the simple example in the documentation http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php ?

Comment: I have tried it many times, not in the unit test, the Memcache class works well, however in the unit test, it tells Memcache class not found.

Comment: Please check and compare the path where you run your unit test vs the other.

Comment: check that the php.ini in use when executing PHPUnit loads the memcache extension

Comment: Check php.ini for all environments.

Comment: As @sectus hints there's a typically a separate php.ini that's used for CLI execution e.g. `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was I had two different php versions installed on my machine. One was with Memcached installed and the other was not. I just ran:

```
$ whereis php
```

And it listed the paths of the two php installations. Then I found which had the Memcached installed by executing:

```
$ /usr/bin/php -i | grep memcache
$ /usr/local/bin/php -i | grep memcache
```

*If none of these return any matches, and you are sure you have Memcached installed, then you are using wrong php.ini as above comments suggested. You can try starting php with -c option, to specify the path to the php.ini:*

```
$ /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

Then it was just a matter of using the correct php path when executing the unit tests:

```
$ /usr/bin/php vendor/bin/phpunit tests
```

Oh, and please note that there are two separate extensions - one is called "[Memcache](http://php.net/memcache)", and the other is "[Memcached](http://php.net/memcached)". If you installed one of it, and try to use the other, it won't work for obvious reasons.